# указательная стрелка-треугольник для popup меню

Tags: html, css, menu, rotate

Всем привет. У меня есть меню (сайдбар), при наведении на соответствующий пункт меню отображается вторая колонка с подменю. Мне нужно сделать треугольник-указатель, как на картинке (в вопросе). Не могу понять, как это можно сделать. Поделитесь мнением, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_sub_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 55px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>1212
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">111</a></li>
                               
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>1313
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">222</a></li>
                          
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде не буду копаться, очень много всего. Просто приведу пример как это сделать, прикрепить к Вашим ссылкам это простая задача (будет как домашнее задание). Прочтите про псевдоэлемент `before` и `after`. В качестве альтернативы, за место данных элементов можете просто поместить абсолютный блок. с теми же стилями.

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #fff;
  right: -7px;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
}

li:hover::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>first</li>
</ul>
```